# Is Gadget on Windows 7 buggy for now?

Tags: windows-7, desktop-gadget

Is Gadget on Windows 7 buggy for now?  For example, I made CPU Meter, Clock "always on top", but sometimes, one is on top but the other is not.  I have to make it "not always on top" and then "always on top" again and it will show up on top again.

another thing that might or might not be a bug is: even when viewing video in full screen mode, the gadgets are all there.  This may be one case where the user won't want all the gadgets on top when viewing a video full screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vista's gadgets were prone to [**severe** memory leaks](http://www.edbott.com/weblog/?p=1616) (that article shows a pretty extreme example). Nevertheless, this can obviously cause bugs.

Windows 7's gadgets are said to be much better in this regard though. Since the RTM build onwards I haven't had any problems. YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced problems in Beta 1 and submitted a bug report - in my case the gadgets app would start and then shut down. I haven't experienced any problems since RC1.

Answer (score 0):

I have found them to be ok whenever I had the urge to use them - but it really depends on the gadget and some are better than others. (And apart from currency converter and weather on occasion, I usually have them turned off).

I do randomly have the problem you said, but then again, I have had a similar problem in random programs ever since Windows 95 where the program that is meant to go on top gets lost, but as you said, turning off and back on fixes it.